# Comparing Vanilla JS and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just found [This](http://vanilla-js.com/) and it has some comparation with JQuery and others...
Its really faster than the others.
What you guys think about this. Is it ok to use only this? Is there anything that you will HAVE/NEED to use JQuery ?

Also, when it comes to performance. Is there a big difference between:

```
var test = document.getElementById('test-table');
test.attr('id','123');  

var test = document.getElementById('test-table');
test.dataset.id = '123';
```

Comment: It's a broad question, this. If not a few questions in one. Which makes it tricky to answer. Basically, jQuery calls 'vanilla'/native JS ultimately anyway. jQuery comes into it's own when dealing with compatibility issues without you ever having to care. Maybe your `attr()` may be a bad example for me to use, but there'll be some functions you can call via jQuery that will consist of fallbacks for older and different browsers that may not be compatible with jQuery's first choice of vanilla JS funciton. It's that sort of behaviour which makes you **want** jQuery, not **need**

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: Is there a specific place to this kind of question ? Sorry for the poor example, I'm a beginner, still studying everything I found. Asked this one because I really could not find the answer by myself ;p

Comment: Love the Vanilla JS link! That said, I use jQuery a lot... maybe more than I need to, but sometimes I just have to get the job done without worrying about Rachel in accounts who's still on IE8. In most cases I'm dealing with at the moment, JS performance isn't the real bottleneck. YMMV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter since you can always wrap any DOM element around a jQuery object if you must.

```
var test = document.getElementById('test-table');
// Do some vanilla stuff
var jTest = $(test);
// Do some jQuery
```

The jQuery library builds upon the DOM API that is available to JavaScript. The only reason you'd need jQuery is to do a complex task that requires more effort in vanilla. In terms of performance, the difference is negligible. jQuery adds checks to be cross-browser compatible. If you code to modern standards, these checks are not necessary.

Comment: What about those comparision on the website ? ops/sec. Is it really that negligible ?

Comment: Are you ever going to need more than 300k lookups in any given DOM?